# AWS SNS message publish success status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am publishing a SNS message from Lambda. In Java, SNS client returns the message ID even if the Lambda does not have permission to write SNS message.

Is there a way of knowing whether message got successfully published?

Following is the code used:

```
        AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .build();
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(topicARN, message);
        PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
        log.info("Published message with ID {}", publishResult.getMessageId());
```

Answer (score 0):

please, check X-Ray, cloudtrail and aws sdk documentation. It'a impossible to use any services without permission. Any aws sdk works same way and throws error if u have not permission. Maybe SNS topic has wide open access policy?